# NWJS - A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, nwjs, node-sqlite3

I'm tryin to build an app which requires sqlite3 Modul.
My app works fine  when I run it from cmd `node server.js`
but when I run it from **NWJS** crashes and throws the error below

```
Uncaught Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
\\?\C:\Users\Coder Bilall\Desktop\My Work\NWJS\GMoney\Gmoney\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v3-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:991:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:831:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1015:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Coder Bilall\Desktop\My Work\NWJS\GMoney\Gmoney\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3-binding.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1161:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:991:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:831:14)
```

My **server.js** Code

```
const express = require('express')
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const LocalStorage = require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage;
let exec = require('child_process').exec, child;
const connectionTester = require('connection-tester');
const notifier = require('node-notifier');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const ToCsv  =  require("sqlite-to-csv");
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const mailjet = require ('node-mailjet')
.connect('878dcf9b5a0ae7cf07498b6ab3d73ca7', 'c6c90ff0878e2b9640a6c342f84e142e')


const db = new sqlite3.Database('mydb.db');
const application = express();
application.use(cookieParser());
const port = 2020;

 application.get('/', (req, res) => {
        
     res.send('Hello World');


    });


 application.listen(port, () => {
     console.log(`Example application listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
 })
```

Please Help me

Answer (score 1):

The code failing is referencing a node binding `sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v3-win32-x64`.

When you `npm install` some node modules will download or build files unique to your operating system (`win32`, `linux`, `darwin`), your architecture (`x86`, `x64`), and your [Node.js ABI Version](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases) (`47`, `72`, `88`). If your globally installed version of Node is not the same as the version built in to NW.js, your module will be incompatible.

**Try this:**

1. Delete your `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`
2. Change your Node.js version to be the same as what is built in to that version of NW.js
3. Then do an `npm install` and see if it works

This may not be your issue, but it may resolve other issues and is quick to test.

**What version of Node.js is in NW.js?**

- https://nwjs.io/versions.json

**How do I switch Node.js versions globally?**

- Uninstall Node.js completely.
- Install a Node Version Manager (nvm):

  - **Linux/OSX**: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm
  - **Windows:** https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows
  - **Windows alternative:** https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist
- Consult the docs for the version of `nvm` you installed. Use it to install and switch to the correct Node.js version

**You may also want to look at this NW.js wiki page:**

- https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Save-persistent-data-in-app#sqlite3